# "smallest" field where a polynomial is reducible

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $f(X)\in \mathbb Q[X]$. Consider the family $\mathcal F(f):=\{\mathbb K|_\mathbb Q : f(X)$ is reducible in $\mathbb K[X]\}$.

Then does $\mathcal F (f)$ always have a minimal element (of course it is non-empty) ?  If it does, then is any two such minimal elements are isomorphic as fields ?

Comment: What does $\mathbb K|_\mathbb Q$ mean? Are you only considering subfields of some field? In that case you can take their intersection. If not, it is not clear to me how your set is defined.

Comment: Yes, it is the splitting field of $f$.

Comment: The splitting field of $f$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, so there is a finite number of intermediate fields.

Comment: @Servaes: I mean field extensions of $\mathbb Q$ ...

Comment: @egreg: well splitting field is definitely in the collection, and since there are a finite number of intermediate fields, so  you are saying there exists a minimal one right ? Is it unique upto isomorphism ?

Comment: @Berci: by user egreg's comment I can see that it exists and contained in the splitting field, but are you claiming it is exactly the splitting field ? How ?

Comment: There is always a minimal element is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a splitting field $F$ for $f$ has been fixed and working only with subfields of $F$, then a minimal extension such that $f$ is reducible exists, because the set is finite: the extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, and so it admits a finite number of intermediate fields.

As far as the isomorphism is concerned, the answer is no.

Consider $f(x)=x^4+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ as $(x^2+i)(x^2-i)$; it is also reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ as $(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)$. Both extensions have degree $2$, so they're surely minimal.

Comment: thanks ... would there be uniqueness if I wanted the smallest field, within the splitting field, in which $f(x)$ has a zero ?

Comment: @user521337 Uniqueness (up to isomorphism) is granted if the polynomial is irreducible.